# Resize rectangle shape at arbitrary origin

Tags: c++, math, geometry, shapes

I have a class named `Rectangle`, which is a 2D shape, with the origin at its center.
`Vec2f` is a `float` bidimensional vector.

```
struct Rectangle {
    Vec2f position, halfSize;
    float getTop() { return position.y - halfSize.y; }
    float getBottom() { return position.y + halfSize.y; }
    // ... getLeft(), getRight(), ...
    void setWidth(float mWidth) { halfSize.x = mWidth / 2.f; }
    // ... setHeight(), setHalfWidth(), ...
};
```

Resizing the shape with `Rectangle::setWidth` obviously maintains the origin in the center. However, I need to arbitrarily resize the rectangle from different points. Example: *I want to resize the rectangle from the bottom-right corner, using the top-left corner as its origin.*

The ideal API would be something like this:

```
Rectangle rect;
rect.resizeFrom(rect.getTopLeft(), Vec2f{150.f, 45.f});
//              ^ new origin       ^ new size
```

My question is: **how can I arbitrarily choose an origin while resizing the rectangle?** I obviously need to perform both a translation and a resize (considering the *real* origin is the center of the rectangle), but I cannot find the correct combination that works with every arbitrary origin.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using OpenGL,

Anyways my recommendation would be,

```
resizeFrom(FROM, Vec2f){
  resize in the normal way
  getTop(), getBottom(), etc.. //get all new corner positions
  Difference = FROM-newLeftCorner
  Move all corner positions according to the Difference
  commit
}
```

I hope I am clear

Comment: It seems to work, but it doesn't solve my original problem: I want to resize a rectangle from the bottom *(think about a shutter)*: the top Y coordinate should stay constant, while what should change is only the bottom Y coordinate.

Comment: to do that you might need a full restructure, ofc its impossible to say without seeing the full code.
if the new rectangle isn't shown until all the calculations are complete, the way you do it may not matter